# How do I clone a fieldset without transfering the values

Tags: javascript, jquery, hidden-field, cloning

I am atempting to clone a fieldset that has selects without cloning the inputs. (I need blanks). I have created a hidden fieldset in the body of the form but not the form itself but I can't seem to get it to work

```
 <div id="analyte" style="display: none">
 <div class="_40">
 <label class="analyte-label" for="analyte">Analyte:</label>
    <input class="analyte" type="text" id="analyte1" name="analyte" value=""> </div>
 <div class="_30">
     <label class="preserved-label" for="preserved">Preserved</label>
 <select class="select_preserved" id="preserved1" name="preserved" data-iconpos="left" data-icon="grid" data-native-menu="false" >
        <option value = ""></option>
           <option value = "HNO3">HNO&#8323;</sub></option>
           <option value = "H2SO4">H&#8322;SO&#8324;</option>
           <option value = "H3PO4">H&#8323;PO&#8324;</option>
           <option value = "HCL">HCL</option>
           <option value = "None1">None</option>
    </select></div></div>
```

I am then using this code in the form

```
 <input type="button" id="add_Analyte" onclick="add_Analyte" value="ADD ANALYTE" /></div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
var _counter = 0;
function add_Analyte() {
_counter++;
var newFields = document.getElementById("Analyte").cloneNode(true);
newFields.id = "";
newFields.style.display = "block";
var newField = newFields.childNodes;
for (var i=0;i<newField.length;i++) {
var theName = newField[i].name
    if (theName)
        newField[i].name = theName + counter;
}
var insertHere = document.getElementById("addAnalyte");
insertHere.parentNode.insertBefore(newFields,insertHere);
}
})
</script>
```

Comment: That script will run before the document is loaded, try wrapping it in `$(document).ready(function(){ /*current code*/ });`

Comment: Thank you - but it didn't help

Comment: if you've `$(document).ready(function(){});` then any particular reason of not using jQuery?

Comment: oops, did notice you hadn't used any actual JQuery. My code wont work if you don;t have a JQuery library included. `window.onload = function(){ };` is a non-jquery alternative

Comment: I thought I was using jQuery. I have jquery 1.7.1 & jquery mobile 1.3.0

Comment: get rid of that `document.ready` actually. Add an `alert("test");` at the top of your code to see if it actual fires onclick. I hate using inline events, but perhaps your html is meant to be `onClick="add_Analyte()"`?

Comment: I think that my problem is the display. After some tweeks and using the test I see it is firing but the block not displaying